# How to call an Asynchronous Method in the background of a Xamarin application

Tags: c#, xamarin, lambda, xamarin.forms

I have a method which I would like to call in the background of xamarin application my application.

I wrote something like this

```
public partial class App : Application
{
  private static Stopwatch stopWatch = new Stopwatch();

   protected override void OnStart()
   {
      if (!stopWatch.IsRunning)
        {
            stopWatch.Start();
        }
      Device.StartTimer(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1),  () =>
        {
             if (stopWatch.IsRunning && stopWatch.Elapsed.Minutes== 2)
            {
                 await myMethod() //This is the method which return a threat I would like to call
                 stopWatch.Restart();
            }
        });

   }
}
```

My Method is something like this:

```
public async static Task <Mytype> myMethod()
{
    MyType myType;

    myType= await SomeMethod();

   return myType;

}
```

When I add `async` to my the method like this

```
protected async override void OnStart()
```

I receive this error

```
    The 'await' operator can only be used within an async lambda expression. Consider marking this lambda expression with the 'async' modifier.
```

When I add the asynchronous lambda expression like this,

```
Device.StartTimer(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1), async () =>
```

I now received this error

```
Cannot convert async lambda expression to delegate type 'Func<bool>'. An async lambda expression may return void, Task or Task<T>, none of which are convertible to 'Func<bool>'.
```

What could be the problem and how can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `myMethod` is returning a `Task`, i.e.:

```
async Task myMethod()
{
    Debug.WriteLine("Processing something....");
    await Task.Delay(1); // replace with what every you are processing....
}
```

Then you can call `Device.StartTimer` in the `OnCreate` like this:

```
Device.StartTimer(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1), () =>
{
    if (stopWatch.IsRunning && stopWatch.Elapsed.Minutes == 2)
    {
        myMethod().ContinueWith((Task t) =>
        {
            stopWatch.Restart();
            return true;
        });
    }
    return true;
});
```